# Magento Block Instantiation Within Block Classes

Tags: php, magento, layout, block, instantiation

I just purchased Alan Storm's pdf book No Frills Magento layout and in the first chapter he talks about binding child block instantiation to a given blocks creation specifically within the _beforeToHtml() method.

In Alan Storm's book he uses this line of code to instantiate a child block

```
$block_2 = new Mage_Core_Block_Text ();
```

I've gotten used to doing something like this

```
 Mage::getModel('modulename/class');
```

Two questions:

1. Is there a better way to instantiate blocks from within a block class
2. What are the benefits of using one vs the other

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you keep with the book it will eventually lead you to the answers you want.  I started with direct class instantiation to show how the system works.

If you can't wait, here's the quick answers

1. `$block_2 = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout')->createBlock('core/text');`
2. When you instantiate the class with it's alias (`core/text`), you're allowing your block to be affected by someone create a class rewrite for your class.

Comment: Im sorry if it seemed like i had jumped the gun. Thanks for all your work.